# Is there a widget that does this, or how would i build this behaviour

Tags: android, ios, flutter

[image]

This is from the 5 minute journal app, when you click on the container, it expands, and you can switch to different containers by clicking on it.
I'm mostly interested in how to build it using flutter

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely require a fair amount of custom code. The general idea in flutter would be to use a hero animation. See the documentation https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out i can achieve this using bottom sheet, or packages that implement material backdrop such as backdrop and sliding_up_panel